# What's Watch process option in netbeans supposed to do?

Tags: netbeans

I have netbeans stuck pushing into a repository (no errors of course, that would be too easy). While clicking around and trying to find out what is wrong, I came across this option:

[image: image description]

I tried clicking on it - I never noticed it before. It doesn't do anything but I have not found any docs on that feature either. The problem is that these keywords match many other things: `netbeans watch process`.

So do you have any idea what is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the netbeans [progress indication documentation](https://ui.netbeans.org/docs/ui/progress_indication/progress_indication_spec.html#4_UI_design), you can find the definition you are looking for:

> - Show Output - opens the appropriate "output" window (valid only when the "output" window exists)
> - **Watch Process - puts process to the status line**
> - Cancel Process - cancels and removes the process from the pop-up list

In the help from the netbeans menu you can find the definition of the status line:

> **Status Line**
> The Source Editor status line is in the bottom right corner of the IDE. The first area of the status line shows the current line number and row number in the form line:row. The second area of the status line indicates the insertion mode (INS or OVR). The text area on the right is used for status messages.

So the watch process option is used to place the selected process in the status line.

Comment: Thank you! Can I just ask for clarification of what that means? It seems that the status line means the bar at the bottom. Do I understand correctly that this option serves for changing the order of processes and displaying the selected one?

Comment: @Tomáš Zato I've completed my answer to take your remark and question into account.